# Clarification of sequence notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

[image]

My question is, why does the sequence have value $\alpha_N$ if $n=j_N$?

Could someone explain that through calculation examples, what is it that I don't see?

Should it be that if $n=j_2$ the sequence is $\alpha_1 e^{j_1} + \alpha_2 e^{j_2}$?

Feel free to explain it like you'd do to a kid.

Comment: Strange notation. $e^j$ is obviously the unit vector with 1 at position $j$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The components of $\mathbb e^{j_k}$ are all zeros, except for the $j_k$-th component, which is $1$. Hence it's $n$-th component is nonzero iff $n=j_k$.